# A Question About The Second Derivative Test

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x,y)$ has a stationary point at $(a,b)$. Let $$D = \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}(a,b) \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^{2}}(a,b)- \left[\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial xy}(a,b) \right]^{2}$$

Does $\dfrac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial xy}(a,b)= \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b) \times\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)$?

Comment: No, it's called a "mixed derivative". Take the partial of $f$ with respect to $y$. Then take the partial of that with respect to $x$. (Maybe I have the order backwards; in most cases it won't matter.)

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, by definition
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial xy} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right]
$$
To show an example: Let $f(x,y) = x^2\sin(y)$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial xy} &= \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial }{\partial y} x^2\sin(y) \\&
= \frac{\partial }{\partial x} x^2\cos(y) \\&= 2x\cos(y)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer and example.